# Tkinter Optionmenu "menu" position showing 0,0 always

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu

I am trying to get the position of the menu that is the child of the option menu widget in tkinter. I want to do this so that I can know when the menu has been shifted due to location on the screen (see picture 1)

[image]

However, when I try and use the menu widget winfo_rootx or winfo_x they both just show position 0 regardless of where the menu actually is. See example code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, BOTH, Menu, Label, SUNKEN, X, BOTTOM
import tkinter as tk
class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, background = "white")
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.geometry("400x100")
        vals = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]
        var = tk.StringVar()
        var.set("1")
        option = tk.OptionMenu(root,var,*vals)
        option.pack()
        self.t = option.children["menu"]
        tk.Menu
        #Do I need to unbind
        #t.bind("<<MenuSelect>>", self.test_func)
        self.t.bind("<<MenuSelect>>", self.test_func)

    def test_func(self,event = None):
        print(self.t.winfo_children())
        print("x,y position",event.widget.winfo_x(),event.widget.winfo_y())
        print("x,y root position",event.widget.winfo_rootx(),event.widget.winfo_rooty())
        #if self.parent.call(event.widget,"index","active") == 0:
            #print(self.t)
root = tk.Tk()
Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I have potentially other options to try and fix this but it seems that there should be a way to get the menu widgets position correctly. My other way is rather hacky and uses the position and lengths of the widgets to try and calculate the adjusted position.

Comment: Why do you need the coordinates? What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: Using Python 3.6.5, I can not reproduce this. The very first time, it shows 0 (is this the problem?), but every time after that the correct position on screen in shown.

Comment: @BryanOakley I am trying to display a "tooltip" dialogue box beside each menu item from the optionmenu. I would like to display it directly beside the option that the user has hovered over. I have completed this task but I specify the position of the tooltip (toplevel) window based on:

the position of the button (optionmneu) widget + the height of the button widget + the index of the currently selected item * the height of each item (calculated by taking the full height of the menu and dividing by the number of items since I don't know how to get the height of each individual menu item).

Comment: Also @tobias_k I am using python 3.6.5 (anaconda distribution and spyder IDE if that is relevant?) and this is the exact code that always prints out (0,0)

Comment: @thatguy14 Have you tried running it directly from the console, i.e. `python3 your_script.py` instead of from within the IDE? Might also be related to operating system, desktop environment, etc.

Comment: @tobias_k I tried doing python my_script.py (python3 did not work as a valid command). I got the same result (position 0,0). I should mention that this is on two separate computers but both use the anaconda custom (64 bit) installation. I also checked my tkinter version which is 8.6. What are you doing with the above code? You should run it, press the option menu and then mouse over, without clicking, the different options and see a print out of the coordinates.

Comment: @thatguy14 That's right. First click shows `0`, then moving the mouse shows the correct position; later clicks and moved always show correct position.

Comment: @tobias_k I am not sure how to fix this then. Any suggestions?

Comment: @BryanOakley Also Bryan did you have any suggestions on what the issue could be? I know you are quite well versed in tkinter